# Measuring corporate size relative to world GDP

Tags: modeling, economics, macro-economics

I'm working o a model where ***corporate revenue / world GDP*** is a dependent variable of some stuff (based on the model proposed in this paper: http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S1807-76922009000200002&script=sci_abstract)

Thing is, I'm not an Economist, so I'm not sure exactly which measures of GDP to use.

On the World Bank website there are four GDP measures: Constant 2010 USD, Current USD, Constant LCU and current LCU.

The companies operate in different currencies and are multinationals, so I was thinking about converting revenues to USD by each year's exchange rate (as recorded by OECD) and dividing it by Current USD GDP values provided by the World Bank.

Does this make sense?

The other way I was thinking is taking constant 2010 USD GDP and inflate/deflate revenues based on CPI Growth (as recorded by OECD) for each currency used in the consolidated income statements of the companies (some companies use Euros and others Yen).

Which one of these would make more sense? If neither one, how would you do it?

Comment: The first one makes more sense and is simpler. The company figures are *current* and are properly comparable to *current* GDP figures. In the second one you introduce an (unnecessary) inflation adjustment which may introduce errors.